# App crashed when downloading video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app im downloading some videos using NSURLConnection. It shows two memory warnings.

```
          Received memory warning. Level=1
          Received memory warning. Level=2
```

And then after sometime the App Crashes is there any way to solve this issue.
Can anyone help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Code i used:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[exer1 objectAtIndex:i-1]]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
     NSLog(@"%@ urlrequest ",theRequest);


        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] retain];

        HUD.labelText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %d Video",[exer1 count]-(i-1)];

        if (theConnection) {
            // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
            // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

        } else {
            // Inform the user that the connection failed.
        }

        }

    }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    expectedLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    currentLength = 0;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;

    NSLog(@"%d expectedLength",expectedLength);

    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    currentLength += [data length];
    HUD.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [HUD hide:YES];
    // release the connection, and the data object
    // [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    // [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

    if(tempz == 1){

        tempz =0;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"The Internet connection appears to be offline." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }



}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *err;
    NSFileManager *fman = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *path = [[[fman URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] path];
    NSDictionary *fattr = [fman attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error:&err];
    //Error checking 
    NSUInteger freeSize = [[fattr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedIntegerValue];

    NSLog(@"Free Space %d", freeSize);

    NSArray* paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    struct statfs tStats;  
    statfs([[paths1 lastObject] cString], &tStats);  
    float total_space = (float)(tStats.f_blocks * tStats.f_bsize);  


    NSLog(@"%f total_space",total_space);



        [SavedVid addObject:[exer1 objectAtIndex:i-1]];
        NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [currentDefaults6 setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:SavedVid] forKey:@"SavedVid"];
        [currentDefaults6 synchronize];


       NSString* cacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Library/Caches"] ;


  /*  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"%@ documentsDirectory",documentsDirectory);
    if (!documentsDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
    }

    */


    NSString *file2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4",cacheDirectory,[elementw.description  objectAtIndex:i-1]];


   /* NSLog(@"%@ documentsDirectory",file2);
      NSLog(@"%@ ---- i elementw.description   ---- %d ",elementw.description,i);
  */
    [receivedData writeToFile:file2 atomically:YES];

   NSLog(@" %@ file 2 ",file2);

    HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]] autorelease];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];


    [self initializPlayer];

    // release the connection, and the data object
   // [connection release];
 //   [receivedData release];
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code for downloading the video, otherwise we have no idea what is really happening.

Comment: @sosborn i have edited my code can you please check

Answer (score 1):

When the data is received, you need to store it in a temporary (or not-so-temporary) file. The problem is that the *whole file* is being download into *memory*, which would consume most of the memory.

The application crashes because it's using too much memory, so writing to a file is the best option.

Something like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    currentLength += [data length];
    HUD.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;

    NSString *temporaryFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/fileDownload.part", NSTemporaryDirectory()];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:temporaryFile]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:temporaryFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:temporaryFile];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:data];
    [fileHandle closeFile];

    if (currentLength == expectedLength) {
        //read from the file stored at temporaryFile
        //perhaps move to a permanent location and change
        //its file name and extension.
    }

}
```

Comment: After i put this code in the App , the download never gets finish. its just gets stuck there.

Comment: I dont know but i still face the same prob. and after a lot of time the next video gets downloaded.Do i need to do anything else in this code?

Comment: Okay.. Well NSTemporaryDirectory() *might* create new directories every time the download method is called. You'll need to create the temporary directory and store it as a string in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, or another method that's called once it's begun downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are keeping the Video in your memory. Depending on the size it can cause memory problems.